# How to create a Keyboard shortcut to turn on/off HOVER feature of "CLICK ASSIST"?

Tags: command-line, shortcuts, accessibility

I'm disabled and use 'click assist', found in Universal Access within settings. I want to be able to turn on/off the hover 'click assist' feature depending on what i'm doing. Is there a command line i can use to turn on/off so I can create a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

The setting can be enabled with the command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.mouse dwell-click-enabled true
```

To disable:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.mouse dwell-click-enabled false
```

To read the current setting:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.a11y.mouse dwell-click-enabled
```

To reset to factory default:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.a11y.mouse dwell-click-enabled
```

Thus, you cn create a shell script that toggles the setting:

```
#!/bin/bash
STATUS=$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.a11y.mouse dwell-click-enabled)
case $STATUS in
    true )
        gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.mouse dwell-click-enabled false
    ;;
    false )
        gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.mouse dwell-click-enabled true
    ;;
esac
```

Save this script in your `~/.local/bin` directory, for example under the name `toggle-dwell-click`, then make the script executable:

```
chmod +x ~/.local/bin/toggle-dwell-click
```

Specify the command `toggle-dwell-click` in the "Command" field of the "Set custom shortcut" dialog.

*Note*: If `~/.local/bin` did not yet exist on your system, you will need to log out then back in before this will work. This is needed to automatically include `~/.local/bin` in your system's search `PATH` for executables.